# Entity framework, code first generation relationship between tables

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm learning EF with MVC and following 
[video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2010/DEV212)
They saying that line :

```
public ICollection<Chirp> Chirps { get; set; }
```

adds the relationship between the two models, but I don't see any difference so far when looking at both tables columns and keys after regenerating tables WITHOUT this line. I'm missing something as this kind of relationship is mentioned in all the tutorials.

```
public class User
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chirp> Chirps { get; set; }
}

public class Chirp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Chirp> Chirps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, does public ICollection Chirps { get; set; } tell EF to do anything with db structure ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You already have the relationship builtin. User is a one to many chirps, and chirp has a one to one relationship back to user. Are you looking for something more?

Comment: @Chris, I see the UserId FK in the Chirp table, but where is the indication of the relationship of User to Chirps (it has a ICollection<Chirp> field)  ? I don't see any with or without that line.

Comment: Is there `UserId` column in your `Chirp` table?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, yes it is there as FK.

Comment: In such case that is your relationship. Just check that it also have referential constraint configured.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, sorry I'm newbie at this. The Contrains folder is epty for Chirps table in management studio, but when I script it out there is: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chirps]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [User_Chirps] FOREIGN KEY([User_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([id])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that difference is in constraint of the Chirps table. Without public ICollection Chirps { get; set; }
its:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chirps]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT **[Chirp_User]** FOREIGN KEY([User_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([id])
```

while with it its :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chirps]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT **[User_Chirps]** FOREIGN KEY([User_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([id]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be generating an additional table that tracks the User to Chirps relationship. Look in your database for a `User_Chirps` or `UserChirps` table that should have two columns, `User_Id` and `Chirp_Id`. Additionally, I just noticed that your id property is using a lowercase i for `id`. I believe that the conventions in Entity Framework are expecting a property name of `Id` with an uppercase I. So you may want to try changing that as well.

Comment: there is no table you are talking about.